# asp.net authentication for application + web api

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I'm developing a MVC web application.

I need to check authentication for the following purposes:

1. Entering the application (users must be logged in).
2. Web api calls from javascript (from within the application).

I created a web api project with the ASP.Net users tables.
On the login of the client side i'm posting a webrequest to get the token.
I store the token in a cookie for the javascript usage (for purpose 2).
It works well.

What is the standard way to get the application to know that the user is logged in (for purpose 1)?
Isn't there an implementation for all of it in the asp.net Identity?

Comment: You send the token up with each request, for both `1` and `2`.  That's how the application authenticates the user.  What other way are you wanting?

Comment: I want all of the Identity values to be set with the login.
So i could use all of the Identity functionality. For example- the webconfig- <deny users="?"/>.

Comment: what's wrong with letting Identity to set the cookie? This way all the request (with JS or not) will be sent with the auth cookie.

Comment: @trailmax, sounds interesting. How can i do that? Any code example?

Comment: ehm.. Just get standard MVC template from VS2013 with Identity authentication. Login as a user through MVC controllers. Then all calls to your WebApi will contain the auth cookie by default , added by the browser (presuming your MVC and WebApi are on the same domain). Unless I'm completely not understanding your question.

Comment: @trailmax, as far as i understand the template's login does not get my web api's token...

Comment: That's the thing, if you get users to login via MVC, you don't need a token. Unless your clients are not logging in via MVC controllers...

Comment: @trailmax, I don't need a token approach the database from within the application, but my web api calls DO REQUIRE A TOKEN for authentication.